# how to start click or change function from inside js

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is,  `$('#menu').val(menu).trigger('change');` and `$('.parentcheck').val(0).attr('checked', true).trigger('click');` changes their state but doesn't fire their functions `$("#menu").change(function () {` and `$(".parentcheck").click(function () {`. How to deal with that problem?

My js code looks like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#parent").hide();
    $(".parentcheck").click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "0") {
            $("#parent").hide().find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');

        }
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
            if ($("#parent option").length > 0) {
                $("#parent").show();
            }

        }
        $("#menu").change();
    });

    $("#menu").change(function () {
        var selectedmenu = $("#menu").val();
        var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();
        if (selectedmenu != '' && selectedmenu != '0') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processor/optionsgenerator.php",
                data: {
                    menu: selectedmenu
                },
                success: function (result, status, xResponse) {
                    if (result != '') {
                        if (parentcheck == '0' || !$(".parentcheck").is(":checked")) {
                            $("#parent").hide();
                        } else {
                            $("#parent").html(result);
                            $("#parent").show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Baza ilə əlaqədə problem var.');
                        $("#parent").hide();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        } else $("#parent").hide();
    });
$('#menu').val(menu).trigger('change'); 
if(parent==0) {
$('.parentcheck').val(0).attr('checked',true).trigger('click');
}
else {
$('.parentcheck').val(1).attr('checked',true).trigger('click');
$('#parent').val(parent);   
}   
    });
```

Comment: Order of operations? The bindings aren't set when the tigger goes to fire...

Comment: lots of negative conditionals there...

Comment: @BradChristie: I can understand the mistake. In JavaScript, it's normal to reference functions before you've defined them. At a glance, triggering an event looks the same as calling a function.

Comment: Does $(".parentcheck") refer to an actual checkbox element?

Comment: @mblase75: Referencing a function handle is one thing, these are triggering events (which have not been bound to). `$('#foo').click(bar); function bar(){}` is acceptable, but calling something that hasn't formally been bound yet is a no-no.

Comment: @BradChristie: Yes, I know -- but I can also understand how one might get the two confused.

Comment: @mblase75 ok all worked. now 1 problem occured: I'm trying to select an option from select menu, generated by js. Trying $('#parent').val(parent); but it doesn't set. how to deal with that? updated code please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering the change before you've defined the `change` handler. Move your `trigger`s to the end of your code block and it'll work fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GreBh/ -- notice that I'm triggering the change twice, but the alert only goes off once.

Comment: ok all worked. now 1 problem occured: I'm trying to select an option from select menu, generated by js. Trying  `$('#parent').val(parent);` but it doesn't set. how to deal with that?

Comment: Please submit that as a separate question, as it is unrelated to this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665675/setting-exact-option-in-select-menu-with-js-generated-on-the-fly